# How does SSL inspection work on personal devices without deploying a trusted custom certificate?

Tags: encryption, tls, man-in-the-middle

My (limited) understanding of SSL inspection is that the process involves deploying a certificate to each host that SSL inspection will be monitoring.

In an enterprise environment, I can understand that the certificates are easily installed as part of a computer's build. However, I have been told that SSL inspection occurs even on guest networks.

How can SSL inspection occur on my personal device if I have not installed the SSL inspection custom certificate? Wouldn't I receive a certificate error when I log into HTTPS sites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It depends.**

For most modern web browsers, you'll be protected by heeding warnings that the site's certificate is untrusted. Of course, most users just look for the "easy button" and click through to the site anyway - so, there goes that protection. What's worse, the default option for some of these warning dialogs will install the site's certificate so you never see the warning there again.

For other apps (mostly mobile apps, but also many desktop-class applications), it's a bit of a crap-shoot. Many aren't using HTTPS to begin with, and many that do won't bother to check the validity of the server's certificate - or, if they do, they either don't do it right or just ignore the errors.

So long as an application isn't properly verifying the server's certificate, or the user happily clicks through any warnings presented, a network owner can proxy the SSL traffic all day without needing the user to actually install their Root CA's certificate.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the explanation. But as long as I'm using Chrome on my personal laptop and am going to a reputable CA authorized website I "should" still see a warning if I haven't installed any intermediary certs by an SSL inspector proxy correct?

Comment: That's correct @Bob

Comment: However, if a organization did buy a sub-CA certificate from a CA and is using that to Proxy HTTPS, you will not see any warnings. Only way to check is to check that the signer name is correct in the certificate details.

Comment: @sebastiannielsen Can you provide an example of what that might look like?

Comment: For example, Google is signed by Google Internet Authority G2 that is in turn signed by GeoTrust. If a Company have a sub-CA certificate, Lets say Stackexchange would have a own CA certificate to virus scan users of their Wifi, it would be that anywhere on the cert path, you would see the StackExchange CA certificate, issued by [some trusted CA]. Note that just checking the first signer is not enough, since the subCA owner can issue a own subCA cert with the "correct" signer name, and in turn sign the website with.